# Play multiple animation when user taps on the screen in Spark AR

Tags: animation, spark-ar-studio

Recently I tried to play multiple animations in spark ar when the user taps on the screen, but it happens only when the animation state is looped. If I uncheck the loop it will stay the previous state. What want to archive is that, when the user taps the screen, play animation 1, user taps play animation 2, user taps play animation 3, user taps play animation 1 likewise. 
How can I overcome this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph that will help you.
Specify durations of each track in options, and max tap count.

[image]